# PYTHON PING IP ADDRESS WITH RESULTS

Tags: python, ping

I am using this code to verify the connection of an ip address using python and this code works for me. However, I would like to use this code to return a value if it has connectivity or not with the ip address. How should I do this?

the code here goes like this:

```
import subprocess
import platform 

ip_addr = '192.168.0.10'

def ping(host):
"""
Returns True if host (str) responds to a ping request.
Remember that a host may not respond to a ping (ICMP) request even if 
the host name is valid.
"""

# Option for the number of packets as a function of
   param = '-n' if platform.system().lower()=='windows' else '-c'

# Building the command. Ex: "ping -c 1 google.com"
   command = ['ping', param, '1', host]

   return subprocess.call(command) == 0



ping(ip_addr)
```

Comment: Check the return code of the process!

Comment: when I tried to print the result= ping(ip_addr), I saw a false/ true...now I get it. thank you for your help and idea. I don't need to get the TTL=64 or those data to check the connection of ip address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to capture the output, or just don't like the way you are doing it currently then you could capture stdout and check the output for a failure string.  You can capture `stdout` like this:

```
def ping(host):
    param = '-n' if platform.system().lower()=='windows' else '-c'
    command = ['ping', param, '1', host]

    result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = result.stdout.decode('utf8')
    if "Request timed out." in output or "100% packet loss" in output:
        return "NOT CONNECTED"
    return "CONNECTED"

print(ping(ip_addr))
```

Comment: thank you for your reply Alexander, but how to verify if there is a connection it will print out "CONNECTED" else "NOT CONNECTED"? the result of the pinging will then compare to a certain value to check whether the ping reply has a response or failed/ timeout.

Comment: @user1505277 try it now

Comment: when I tried to print the result= ping(ip_addr), I saw a false/ true...now I get it. thank you for your help and idea. I don't need to get the TTL=64 or those data to check the connection of ip address.